# How to avoid the unwanted use of "Attach to the process " in Visual Studio 2008 in Windows XP?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am working on Visual Studio 2008.  I have this problem with Windows XP.  I have no problems debugging when the process starts but after a while it just disconnects then I need to  attach to the process manually and after a longer while it again disconnects.I am seriously frustrated with this ,I had uninstalled the VS 2008 and re-installed my IIS and intalled the VS 2008 again but still the same problem.

Initially VS will automatically attach, it will continue to do so on successive debug commands, but eventually after a while it stops attaching and it must be done manually.  Hitting debug does everything, builds, starts the development server, opens the page and simply fails to attach.

It would be very helpful to have a resolution to this.

Comment: I have never seen this problem, or anything like it. This sounds like a problem specific to your environment. Do you have anti-virus running?

Answer (score 0):

Replace file webdev.webserver.exe in visula studio installed folder
i had the same problem once i was working in vs 2008. It will only occur when you try to run two different instances of visual studio projects 
I now work in vs 2010 and i forgot the path  but you will find it by googling